# How to Tokenize the word data column having multiple language with better accuracy.?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, multilingual

Working on a multilingual classification data-set, Where one of the column have the text in multiple language, I have tried using the simple Tokenization but it has the lower accuracy rate .

I have used simple tokenizer, But the accuracy rate is much lower.

Dataset have a column with multilanguage text.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=18, lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data.overview)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data.overview)
x = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=18)
```

I have checked on the **universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large** on TF-Hub but it is not integrating with the keras model.

Answer (score 0):

`num_words` in the `Tokenizer` constructor isn't the sequence length, it's the size of the vocabulary to use. So, you are setting the tokenizer to only keep the 18 most common words. A value around 10,000 to 100,000 is likely to work better, depending on what the dataset you're using looks like.